# Show Meta Box On Specific Page Template

Tags: metabox

Is there a way to show custom page settings on specific page templates ONLY?

For instance I have a settings field: "Custom Settings". I don't want this to show on the "Default Page Template". I only want it to display if we select the "Custom Page Settings Page Template".

Here's my meta box code:

```
function cd_meta_box_add()  
{  
add_meta_box( 'icon-class-meta-box', 'Icon Class', 'ic_meta_box_cb', 'page', 'side', 'default' );  
}  
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' ); 

function ic_meta_box_cb( $post)  
{  
$values = get_post_meta( $post->ID );   
$selected = isset( $values['ic_meta_box_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['ic_meta_box_select'][0] ) : ”;  

wp_nonce_field( 'ic_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' ); 
?>  
<p>  
    <label for="ic_meta_box_select">Class</label>  
    <select name="ic_meta_box_select" id="ic_meta_box_select">
        <option value=" " <?php selected( $selected, ' ' ); ?>> </option> 
        <option value="red" <?php selected( $selected, 'red' ); ?>>red</option>  
        <option value="blue" <?php selected( $selected, 'blue' ); ?>>blue</option>
        <option value="green" <?php selected( $selected, 'green' ); ?>>green</option>
        <option value="pink" <?php selected( $selected, 'pink' ); ?>>pink</option>
        <option value="orange" <?php selected( $selected, 'orange' ); ?>>orange</option>
        <option value="black" <?php selected( $selected, 'black' ); ?>>black</option>
    </select>  
</p>
<?php    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use CSS and jQuery for this type of thing by hooking `admin_head`. This should be done client-site as a user has an option to select your template or another one after DOM load. Basically, all you do is check if the value is set for `#page_template` and toggle `show/hide` if your template is selected or not.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'metabox_switcher' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'metabox_switcher' );

function metabox_switcher( $post ){

    #Isolate to your specific post type
    if( $post->post_type === 'page' ){

        #Locate the ID of your metabox with Developer tools
        $metabox_selector_id = 'id-of-your-metabox';

        echo '
            <style type="text/css">
                /* Hide your metabox so there is no latency flash of your metabox before being hidden */
                #'.$metabox_selector_id.'{display:none;}
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                    //You can find this in the value of the Page Template dropdown
                    var templateName = \'template-folder/file-name.php\';

                    //Page template in the publishing options
                    var currentTemplate = $(\'#page_template\');

                    //Identify your metabox
                    var metabox = $(\'#'.$metabox_selector_id.'\');

                    //On DOM ready, check if your page template is selected
                    if(currentTemplate.val() === templateName){
                        metabox.show();
                    }

                    //Bind a change event to make sure we show or hide the metabox based on user selection of a template
                    currentTemplate.change(function(e){
                        if(currentTemplate.val() === templateName){
                            metabox.show();
                        }
                        else{
                            //You should clear out all metabox values here;
                            metabox.hide();
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfect for what I was doing. Thanks =D

Comment: $post return nothing in my case, so post type check fails. I removed $post parameter and added it as a global variable and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_product_meta');
function add_product_meta() {
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post)) {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-templates/product-page.php' ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'product_meta', // $id
                'Product Information', // $title
                'display_product_information', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}

function display_product_information() {
    // Add the HTML for the post meta
}
```

Comment: This will not work when you are going to create new page